# RemoveChild and Error 2025

Tags: actionscript-3, null

I'd like to remove a child (background) via another class. I can't seem to be able to target it! It always returns me null or error 2025 and stuff... hehe.

I have the background in my class **creationObjets**:

```
package cem{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class creationBackground extends Sprite{

        public function creationBackground() {
            switch(monterJeu._Difficulte){
                case 0:
                    backgroundFacile();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    backgroundMoyen();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    backgroundDifficile();
                    break;
            }
        }
        private function backgroundFacile():void{
            var backgroundStage:Sprite = new Sprite();
            backgroundStage.graphics.beginFill(0x8FCCA8);
            backgroundStage.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(750,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(750,450);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(0,450);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.endFill();

            this.addChild(backgroundStage);
        }
        private function backgroundMoyen():void{
            var backgroundStage:Sprite = new Sprite();
            backgroundStage.graphics.beginFill(0x8F3378);
            backgroundStage.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(750,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(750,450);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(0,450);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.endFill();

            this.addChild(backgroundStage);
        }
        private function backgroundDifficile():void{
            var backgroundStage:Sprite = new Sprite();
            backgroundStage.graphics.beginFill(0x233378);
            backgroundStage.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(750,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(750,450);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(0,450);
            backgroundStage.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
            backgroundStage.graphics.endFill();

            this.addChild(backgroundStage);
        }
    }
}

public static var _creationBackground:creationBackground = new creationBackground();
```

below, I add it:

```
addChild(_creationBackground);
```

then I want to remove it from another class **actionObjets**! How can I get to my background?
I tried

`creationObjets._creationBackground.parent.removeChild(creationObjets._creationBackground);`

```
removeChild(creationObjets._creationBackground);
```

I really have no idea how to access it!

Comment: Excluding the last line of code (the removeChild) it is correct (albeit an ugly way). I suspect there is something else causing the problem.

Comment: Because what i'd like to do is only call the class, then a variable or function inside (would be easier), but can't seem to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but:

Remember that in order to remove a child you need access to the child's stage. If your actionObjects class is a Movieclip or sprite it will have a read-only variable that will reference the stage (which may or may not be the same as the stage you added _creationBackground too).

So for instance:

```
stage.removeChild(_creationBackground);
```

Should work fine if actionObjets has the same stage as wherever you added _creationBackground.

If actionObjets does not have the same stage or has none at all (maybe it isn't a sprite or movieclip?) You can pass in the stage where _creationBackground was added.

IE:

package {

```
import flash.display.Stage;

public class actionObjets {

    private var myStage:Stage;

    public function actionObjets(s:Stage) {
        myStage = s;
    }
}
```

}

and then try:

```
 myStage.removeChild(_creationBackground);
```

This is of course assuming that you have access to the _creationBackground clip inside actionObjets.

Not sure if this addressed your problem or not,
good luck.

Comment: Hehe I tried that! It doesn't have the same stage (it was created in another class)  Line 199 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeChild through a reference with static type Class.
Line 199 1120: Access of undefined property _creationBackground.
These are the two errors I get with : creationObjets.removeChild(_creationBackground); (creationObjets is the class where I added the background)

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following should suffice:

```
creationObjets.removeChild(creationObjet.getChildAt(0));
```

or

```
creationObjets.removeChild(creationObjet.getChildByName("creationBackground"));
```

or

```
creationObjets.removeChildAt(0);
```

When you use removeChildAt() or getChildAt() you must specify the display object's(that you want to get or remove) index position. The index position is the position of the display object in the display list of the display object container(I've made the assumption that its 0).

Also when using getChildByName() you must specify the name of the display object that you want to get. Note that you must set the name property of the display object first.

Here's a working example based on you flash app/movie:

```
package
{
    import cem.CreationObjet;
    import cem.ActionObjet;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main():void
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            var creationObjet:CreationObjet = new CreationObjet();
            addChild(creationObjet);

            var actionObjet:ActionObjet = new ActionObjet(creationObjet);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

In the document class Main, first CreationObjet and ActionObjet is imported. Next an instance of the CreationObjet is declared, instantiated and added to the stage. Lastly an instance of the ActionObjet is declared, instantiated and the instance of CreationObjet is parsed as its only argument.

```
package cem
{
    import cem.CreationBackground;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class CreationObjet extends Sprite
    {
        private var _creationBackground:CreationBackground;

        public function CreationObjet():void
        {
            _creationBackground = new CreationBackground();
            addChild(_creationBackground);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

In the CreationObjet class, an instance of CreationBackground is added to the CreationObjet display object.

```
package cem
{
    import cem.CreationObjet;

    public class ActionObjet
    {
        private var _creationObjet:CreationObjet;

        public function ActionObjet(p_creationObjet:CreationObjet):void
        {
            _creationObjet = p_creationObjet;

            _creationObjet.removeChild(_creationObjet.getChildAt(0));
            // or _creationObjet.removeChild(_creationObjet.getChildByName("creationBackground"));
            // or _creationObjet.removeChildAt(0);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Finally in ActionObjet class, the CreationBackground display object is removed from the CreationObjet.

I've had to make a bunch of assumptions about your flash app/movie, but this should give you a general idea of how to implement what I suggested before.

I hoped this helped :)

Comment: This is obviously a nicer approach but I think Elggetto's code structure is quite different. From the look of his/her code I suspect ActionObjet has no references to CreationObject which is why the creationBackground instance is static so that Elgetto can simply call the class creationObjets (not the instance) from any class and then have access to the _creationBackground variable. Then by calling the parent and removing the child it should be removed. So I am thinking that the problem might be elsewhere in his code...

Comment: Wow! that's a lot of text! Thanks. I kind of understand, what you're saying, but not all... Here you say: var creationObjet:CreationObjet = new CreationObjet(); But all it does is removing the child.. no?

Comment: Allan... yup you got it. So you think the problem is elsewhere? I have no idea where. awww :(

Comment: @Taurayi also I think for your example you would be better off making a getter for _creationBackground in the CreationObjet so that in the ActionObjet instead of _creationObjet.removeChild(_creationObjet.getChildAt(0)) you can instead do _creationObjet.removeChild(_creationObjet.creationBackground). I think this way is a bit safer as at some point _creationBackground might no longer be at index 0.

Comment: @Allan Oh I read about that but I don't really understand how to do that. Also, my code is so bad written that it's hard to try to rearrange things. What I understand of getter is that it's only a function that returns something..? I just don't know where I need to put it and again, how to access it.

Comment: @Elggetto - One thing to check is that you are not removing it twice.

Comment: @Elggetoo - ok so you basically have two choices. Either persist with how you have structured everything. The way you are removing is correct, so that line of code is not the problem. Or you can restructure it towards Taurayi's answer, although you may still have a bug due to not fixing the original problem depending on what it is.

Comment: @Allan - Thx for the help. A friend came home and helped me get through this! He showed me a bit of getters and other stuff i'm not sure about... :P !

Comment: @Allan your right, I had a feeling that it was something along those lines, but I still wasn't sure about the design and purpose of the flash app/movie so I went with what I thought was a more simple and common example. I think I could offer a better answer if I new the source code for all the classes involved in the flash app/movie. Your also right about the getter method too. I'll edit my answer so it includes creationBackground and I'll explain getter and setter methods if Elggetto wants. I just don't know whether I should since my example seems to take a different approach to Elggetto's.